# ActionBarCompat is truncating title messages abnormally

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using the actionbarcompat library but I am facing a strange issue.In the action bar title is truncated abnormally. I don't know what is the reason.

[image: Full Title]

[image: Truncated Message]

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem and did not find a solution...

Comment: @BlaBlub: Nope. I could not solve.

Comment: @BlaBlub: Could you find any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @jennymo: It is resolved in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out what the reason could be. And this is what I think.

I was setting the action bar title from the child fragment when using the ViewPager.

Instead what I am doing now is I am setting the title from the Fragment which is holding the ViewPager.

So it works properly now.